# Org-mode TODO items strange behaviour

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have moved my org-files from "~/local_computer/org/" to "~/Dropbox/org/" in order to be able to work on the files on separate computers.
Opening my inbox.org on my new computer, all old TODO-items are not bold as they are supposed to be. My old TODO-items are not listed in the global list of TODO items. When I choose "show TODO tree" in my inbox.org, all my TODO-items are highlighted.

When a change a TODO-state to DONE it changes from
* TODO Work
to
* DONE TODO Work

I can however capture a new TODO-item:
* **TODO** Sleep
and change the state to a non-bold DONE-state:
* DONE Sleep
But when I change it to TODO again, it goes:
* TODO DONE Sleep

Update:
When I delete the priority tag, the TODO-keyword becomes bold:
* TODO [#A] Buy milk
->
* **TODO** Buy milk
However, when I change the TODO-state from TODO to DONE back to TODO, the headline is destroyed and un-bold:
* TODO DONE Buy milk

Comment: Did you verify that the orgmode installations/configurations are identical on both computers?

Comment: Doublechecked, and yes. My .emacs=(setq user-emacs-directory "~/Dropbox/.emacs.d/")
(load "~/Dropbox/.emacs.d/init.el")

Comment: Solution: My TODO-keywords "fast selection/timestamp/note"-syntax was messed up. Now corrected and TODO-states works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My TODO-keywords "fast selection/timestamp/note"-syntax was messed up. Now corrected and TODO-states works fine